# Local Biot-Savart law in $B(x_o,r) \subset \mathbb R^2$

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, parabolic-pde, differential-calculus

Let $u: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ and let $\omega = \text{curl } u$ be the 2D vorticity of $u$, where $u, \omega \in L^2(\mathbb R^2)$ and $\nabla \cdot u = 0$. The classical Biot-Savart law states that
$$
u_1(x) = -\frac1{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb R^2}\frac{x_2-y_2}{|x-y|^2}\omega(y) \, dy
$$
and
$$
u_2(x) = \frac1{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb R^2}\frac{x_1-y_1}{|x-y|^2}\omega(y) \, dy.
$$

I am interested in a local version of the law in $B(x_o, r) \subset \mathbb R^2$. More precisely, suppose $u: \Omega \to \mathbb R^2$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^2$ is bounded, and $u, \omega \in L_{loc}^2(\Omega)$ with $\nabla \cdot u = 0$. Is it true that
$$
u_1(x) = -\frac1{2\pi}\int_{B(x_o,r)}\frac{x_2-y_2}{|x-y|^2}\omega(y) \, dy+A_1^{x_o}(x)
$$
and
$$
u_2(x) = \frac1{2\pi}\int_{B(x_o,r)}\frac{x_1-y_1}{|x-y|^2}\omega(y) \, dy+A_2^{x_o}(x).
$$
for all $x \in B(x_o,r) \subset \Omega$ and for some smooth-ish function $A^{x_o}$? If not this, is there something similar which is true?

Finally, I am also interested in the general case of $\mathbb R^d$ for $d >2$, but for simplicity we may first restrict to the case $d=2$.

Comment: Probably you meant to assume that your $u$ is divergence free ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember how the classical Biot-Savart law is obtained : first, you take the curl of the defining equation $\omega = \nabla \wedge u$, and then, you use the fact that you know the solution of the Poisson equation in terms of the source. So, your problem boils down to computing explicitly some kernel.

Let's go through the proof in the 2D case, the necessary modifications for 3D and higher being easy.

First, extend $\omega$ by $0$ outside $\Omega$ and denote this extension by $\tilde{\omega}$. Now, $\tilde{\omega}$ is defined on the plane.

Let $\varphi$ be the unique solution in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ (actually also in $H^2$) of the Poisson equation $\Delta \varphi = \tilde{\omega}$. Define a new vector field $v := \nabla^{\perp} \varphi$, i.e.

$$v_1 = -\partial_2 \varphi \quad , \quad v_2 = \partial_1 \varphi .$$

Obviously, $\nabla \cdot v = 0$ and $\nabla \wedge v = \tilde{\omega}$. Thus, on $\Omega$, $u$ and $v$ agree up to a harmonic polynomial, which is smooth anyway.

Now, take a compact subset $K$ of $\Omega$ and choose a fattening $K'$ of $K$, that is, another compact subset of $\Omega$ whose interior contains $K$. $K'$ may very well be a set of the type $K_{\varepsilon} := \{x \in \Omega ; \text{dist}(x,K) \leq \varepsilon \}$ for some small $\varepsilon$.

Write $v = v_1 + v_2$ with $v_1 := \int_{K'} \nabla_x \left( \ln |x-y| \right) \omega (y) \: dy$ and $v_2$ is the same integral, but over the complement of $K'$.

As $v_2$ is harmonic over $K$, with the boundary of $K$ uniformly far from that of $K'$, $v_2$ enjoys both smoothness and integrability over $K$.

Up to some possible harmonic polynomial, this may satisfy you, I hope.

(On a side note : are you working with or around Navier-Stokes and fluid mechanics ?)

Comment: So $v$ and $u$ agree modulo a harmonic function, which would be my $A^{x_o}$ I suppose. And then one uses the Green's function in a ball to solve for $\varphi$. And then one may differentiate $\varphi$ to obtain $v_1$ and $v_2$. Seems doable although tedious. But now the Green's function should include a boundary term, right? So there should be a boundary term also in the Biot-Savart law in a bounded domain?

Comment: And yes I have been studying Navier-Stokes theory and I am just trying to understand how some of these things work in a local setting. So eventually I would also like to understand this in a time-dependent setting, i.e. I would like to have some time regularity from my error function $A$, as well, if possible.

Comment: I did some more calculations. At least in the case of a ball $B(0,1)$ the boundary term, indeed, disappears. However, the other integral seems to be $\int_{K'} \nabla_x \ln (|x||y-x/|x|^2|)\omega(y) \, dy$, which seems to have a singularity in the origin, if I did not do a mistake. On the other hand, I found the results as a Lemma in one of Serrin's papers, so I guess it must be true, but unfortunately Serrin did not provide a transparent proof.

Comment: I have also studied Serrin's article for a few weeks and yes, he has a quite... concise style, at the very least. I suggest you follow his proof step by step, with more modern notations and more explicit integral splittings like I did above. Eventually, you will be a little bit more convinced than you seem to be now. :)

Getting time-regularity is not something you do directly on your $A$, since it is only harmonic in space "locally uniformly in time", so you will not do better than $L^{\infty}_t$ in this way. (1/2)

Comment: On the other hand, I have a more detailed proof of Serrin's result, which also includes an extension from Fabes, Jones and Rivière (equality in Serrin's condition and regularity up to the final time). Disclaimer : the style is quite informal, as it was some kind of writing exercise from my advisor and it's written in French (it was never intended to be used anywhere else). If you wish, you can give me your email and I will send it to you.

Comment: Thanks! That would be great. My e-mail address is firstname.lastname@gmail.com.

Comment: Thanks for the notes. I was trying to use the Poisson kernel for the ball to obtain the claim, but then I encountered the integral in my above comment. This has a singularity at $x=0$. But what you are doing, it seems, is that you actually introduce a cut-off function. And then you are able to show a version of the Biot-Savart law where you have the truncated vorticity on the right hand side, right? But this is not really what I was after (although it seems to work for NS). In this case, you do not actually have the vorticity of $u$ on the RHS, but the truncated vorticity, instead.

Comment: So in order to use this result, you need to be able to show that if you truncate your solution, it is still a solution to some nice equation(?). In particular, it seems that one needs some properties of the Navier-Stokes equation. But if I just want to have a general local version of the Biot-Savart law without the truncations, I might have some problems, I guess? On the other hand, Serrin claims the result in full generality. Although, I wonder what does he mean by "$*u$".

Comment: The star is the Hodge-star, something from differential geometry we absolutely don't care about usually (and Serrin could have written his article without it, actually). In dimension $n$, it transforms $k$-forms into $(n-k)$-forms. In dimension $3$, this amounts to identifying the curl of a vector field, which is an antisymmetric $3 \times 3$ matrix, to a vector field. In dimension $2$, the curl is really a volume form, but volume forms are always a multiple of the usual one, given by the Lebesgue masure. The multiple is what we call the scalar vorticity (in dimension $2$ only, remember).

Comment: Most usual kernels _do_ possess singularities at the origin anyway, think about the heat kernel on $\mathbb{R}^n$ or the inverse laplacian kernel in our case.

Regarding the equation satisfied by the truncated velocity/vorticity, you don't need to know much things on NS beyond the existence of Leray solutions and properties thereof (namely, they lie in $L^{\infty}L^2 \cap L^2H^1$). What happens is that you have some complicated equations _on the truncation_, with secondary terms which exist _independantly of the truncation_, thanks to Leray's theorem.

Comment: Then, a fixed-point argument shows that the truncation may be expressed as a linear, neither smoothing nor singular, transform of a regular remainder, which mostly closes the proof.

Comment: Ok, so in general, I can always write the Biot-Savart law in $\mathbb R^2$ and then use this cut-off trick to write it in two parts - just by introducing an appropriate cut-off function. Then, since $\omega \in L^\infty(L^1)$, this error term is always uniformly bounded in time in $K$, and it is also harmonic. So this actually seems to work as long as $\omega \in L^\infty(L^1)$. I will have the truncation of $\omega$ on the RHS, but that is not so bad. And $u$ is defined in all $\mathbb R^2$ as the vector field inducing the extended $\tilde \omega$, but in $K$ this agrees to the original $u$.

Comment: I think you got the spirit, now it's up to you to play with assumptions and/or to use the results for your own research. :)

Comment: Yup, the only thing I am still wondering is that I only know that $v$ and $u$ agree up to a harmonic function (for each $t$). So in the time-dependent case I still need to show that also this additional harmonic function can be bounded uniformly in time. But this should not be too difficult.